# A Ruby NameError, undefined local variable, was defined

Tags: ruby, scope

I made a simple hash fetching app that retrieves a postal code territory based on the first character of a user's input. But I keep getting this error

> postal_code_lookup.rb:27:in `lookup_code': undefined local variable or
>   method`postal_codes' for main:Object (NameError) Did you mean? 
>   postal_code

I'm confused because I have declared the variable and it should be available to me in my loop.

```
postal_codes = {
  V: "British Columbia",
  Y: "Yukon Territory",
  X: "Northwest Territory",
  T: "Alberta",
  S: "Saskatechewan",
  R: "Manitoba",
  P: "Northern Ontario",
  M: "Toronto",
  L: "Central Ontario",
  K: "Eastern Ontario",
  J: "Western & Northern Quebec",
  N: "Western Ontario",
  G: "Eastern Quebec",
  H: "Metroplitan Montreal",
  A: "Newfoundland & Labradour",
  C: "Prince Edward Island",
  E: "New Brunswick",
  B: "Nova Scotia"
}


def lookup_code(postal_code)
  territory = postal_codes.fetch(postal_code[0].upcase.to_sym)
  puts "Your address is in #{territory}"
end

loop do 
  puts "Do you want to lookup a postal code?(Y/n)"
  prompt = gets.chomp.downcase
  if prompt != "y"
    break
  end

print "Enter your postal code > "
postal_code = gets.chomp

lookup_code(postal_code)

end
```

What am I not understanding about the scope here?

Comment: "I'm confused because I have declared the variable and it should be available to me in my loop." – Did you even read the error message you posted? The error is on line 27, which is not in your loop. Your loop has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sure it is.... the method causing error is defined on line, containing the postal_codes variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods introduce new scope. They are not closures: one should not expect that local variables from the parent scope would be accessible there in the nested scope.

#### Solution 1: Use constant

```
POSTAL_CODES = {
  V: "British Columbia",
  # SKIPPED
  B: "Nova Scotia"
}


def lookup_code(postal_code)
  territory = POSTAL_CODES.fetch(postal_code[0].upcase.to_sym)
  puts "Your address is in #{territory}"
end
```

#### Solution 2: Use an instance variable

Despite that you have no class, there is `main`, which is a special instance of `Object`, always defined:

```
@postal_codes = {
  V: "British Columbia",
  # SKIPPED
  B: "Nova Scotia"
}


def lookup_code(postal_code)
  territory = @postal_codes.fetch(postal_code[0].upcase.to_sym)
  puts "Your address is in #{territory}"
end
```

#### Solution 3: Use a global variable

```
$postal_codes = {
  V: "British Columbia",
  # SKIPPED
  B: "Nova Scotia"
}


def lookup_code(postal_code)
  territory = $postal_codes.fetch(postal_code[0].upcase.to_sym)
  puts "Your address is in #{territory}"
end
```

#### Solution 4: Abuse OOP

One might (bah!) create a class here and use it’s instance:

```
class Lookup
  def postal_codes
    @postal_codes ||= {
      V: "British Columbia",
      # SKIPPED
      B: "Nova Scotia"
    }
  end

  def lookup_code(postal_code)
    territory = postal_codes.fetch(postal_code[0].upcase.to_sym)
    puts "Your address is in #{territory}"
  end
end

Lookup.new.lookup_code("01234")
```

#### Solution 5 (credits to @ndn): Inline a hash

```
def lookup_code(postal_code)
  territory = {
    V: "British Columbia",
    # SKIPPED
    B: "Nova Scotia"
  }.fetch(postal_code[0].upcase.to_sym)
  puts "Your address is in #{territory}"
end
```

Comment: a global variable would also be possible or?

Comment: @ndn Updated. Also, one might `require('open-uri'); open('http://www.geopostcodes.com/canada?') ; parse(...)` :)

Comment: Thank you mudasobwa! I didn't realize methods did not function as closures... Coming from JavaScript I just assumed they would have access to variables in the higher scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
@postal_codes = {
  V: "British Columbia",
  Y: "Yukon Territory",
  X: "Northwest Territory",
  T: "Alberta",
  S: "Saskatechewan",
  R: "Manitoba",
  P: "Northern Ontario",
  M: "Toronto",
  L: "Central Ontario",
  K: "Eastern Ontario",
  J: "Western & Northern Quebec",
  N: "Western Ontario",
  G: "Eastern Quebec",
  H: "Metroplitan Montreal",
  A: "Newfoundland & Labradour",
  C: "Prince Edward Island",
  E: "New Brunswick",
  B: "Nova Scotia"
}

def lookup_code(postal_code)
  territory = @postal_codes.fetch(postal_code[0].upcase.to_sym)
  puts "Your address is in #{territory}"
end
```